# Fixing traverse on Guldmann GH2 (old title: Measuring EMF and terminal voltage with multiple batteries)

Tags: voltage, batteries, dc, emf, terminal

Suppose we have two 12V batteries as our source voltage.  How can the EMF and terminal voltage be measured when using one 12V battery versus both batteries?  Since terminal voltage deals with a closed circuit, do we need more details?  Feel free to make them up.

See GH2HD:

https://www.rdbatteries.com/medical-batteries/guldmann/

This question led me to a theory I have that may be causing my issue, but I'm no electrical engineer, so I might be down the wrong path here.

[Mysterious voltage drop then slows climbs back up when powered off](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/103515/mysterious-voltage-drop-then-slows-climbs-back-up-when-powered-off)

Here's why:

I rely on a ceiling lift to transfer to/from my wheelchair in my home and the manufacturer stopped servicing this lift.  It's roughly $5000 per lift and the new model is more expensive.  This is the second lift I bought and I have the exact same anomaly I had with the old one.  Let me explain the behavior and maybe you can give me better direction on this.

There are four directions my lift will move.  Up, down, traverse left and traverse right.  The up/down is controlled by the nylon strap you see in the image I found online.  The strap coils up inside the lift/hoist with a motor.  I believe there is another motor for the traverse (or two depending) for the hoist to move along the rail above it on the ceiling using a trolley.

When the lift is in good working condition, the traverse shuts off when the 12V batteries are low.    Probably for safety.  That way you can move down to get out before the batteries are discharged.  But maybe this is not for safety because I've always been able to go down in these situations and then traverse, and it works.  So it could be oversight.  Regardless, that behavior is there under "nominal" conditions, before I explain the actual issue which began two weeks ago for my current lift.

About every 2-3 days, the traverse shuts off when the low battery indicator LED on the lift is NOT blinking, meaning the battery still has plenty of power.  Or so I can tell.  I can fix the issue by doing one of two things.  I'm not 100% confident of #1, because it never works on the first try.  I usually unhook from the lift, go do something (to yell nicely) and then come back, and it works.  But the second fix happened last night by accident after doing #1, testing with no success of traverse, and then #2 about 10 minutes later realizing the battery was then dead when I got back in.  Hoping to do more tests with no shaking (#1) soon!!!  Maybe it's voltage simply drops suddenly, turning off the traverse, as in nominal conditions.  Could this be due to bad batteries, a bad circuit board or a bad motor?  Which one sounds most plausible?

#1.) Raising myself up all the way by having the strap coil inside the hoist, then rocking myself in the air, thus shaking the lift.  Low battery indicator LED on the lift IS NOT blinking.

#2.) Using up the power by going up and down several times (with no shaking).  Low battery indicator LED on the lift IS blinking

[image]

Found the electrical schematic of the traverse drive motor PCB if that helps.  Go here and download the pdf file.  Then look at pages 59 and 60.  The pages seem different when reading it in the browser.  From Google Chrome, it appears to be pages 57 and 58.

https://www.manualslib.com/manual/2525673/Guldmann-Gh2.html?page=59#manual

Comment: My comment is, it's far more common for problems to be MECHANICAL than ELECTRICAL in nature.  You having to shake the machine suggests that to be so here.   It's possible (almost certain) that the motors have over-current shut offs  i.e. they draw too much power, they stop.  If you were having some mechanical issue i.e. friction going up or maybe hair/fibers stuck in a bearing, grease drying out, etc (Anything that increases the mechanical load) .. That would increase the drive current.

Comment: Last night, I simply waited for two minutes (without shaking or any movement of the lift) and it worked.  So I'm suspecting one or both batteries are bad.

Comment: Use a voltmeter, and watch directly at the battery terminals when operating.  If the voltage goes down less than maybe 1 or 2 V  (i.e. to 11 or 10V) you're probably OK.  If you have "bad batteries" it'll drop way lower.    Below 8V definitely bad.   Watch specifically when the motors should be running.

Comment: I have a very convincing theory that is causing this.  Single Event Upsets are known to be caused by radioactive cosmic rays from the sun.  However, I believe this is caused by the sun causing me stress (perhaps due to these bit flips from the sun) because when I'm angry, this happens!  I finally remembered that my internet kept going out when this happened with the last hoist.  And it's been failing when my lift fails!!  Basically the sun might be causing the PCB in the hoist and my internet connection to fail, and my stress.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaZ_RSt0KP8

Comment: Because for the last 8 days, it's been working fine!

Comment: Cosmic ray bit flipping is a thing, but it's EXTREMELY RARE.   Like the kind of thing might happen once in a lifetime.  It's not happening to you over & over I promise.  If IC's were that sensitive to cosmic ray bit flipping, nobodies cell phone would work for more than a few hours.

Comment: Are the wi-fi and your machine on the same circuit?  Perhaps when you start using the machine, it pulls down the power line voltage ("brown out")

Comment: internet is AC.  lift is DC when in use, but is charged with AC

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580933/cosmic-rays-what-is-the-probability-they-will-affect-a-program

Comment: Occams razor brother ---  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor

Comment: Within a couple weeks, we'll test the battery.  I can't do it myself.  My gut is telling me it's a combination of simple things causing it to fail and mysteriously begin working.

Comment: Voltage was fine on the batteries, but we changed them during my regular 9 month maintenance anyway so they last longer.  Still can't explain those weird situations, but at least it works now!

Comment: @KyleB, it seems you were right!  Occams Razar!  Few days shy of a month without an issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer:

People who were simply staring at my Facebook profile for hours upon hours were causing my ceiling lift to stop working.  Turns out that humans can create the same effect that a Single Event Effect creates with a transistor flipping.  But instead, the human body can create the same effect with a transistor (of the traverse motor of the Guldmann GH2) if a person is around people they are not compatible with.  This was also happening with a caregiver on days she was helping me, which allowed me to prove it!  Then I found others that were causing it.  Ultimately the my digestion was causing it, but people we know and digestion  are in symbiosis.  Unfriending these people and staying away from this caregiver fixed the issue!!!!!!!  After doing this, my health started getting extremely better, and my constipation issue I had for 14 years is now gone!  Thank God!  And if you think I'm joking, you better re-read this and believe it!  Because it's true!  I also caused the automatic door at the ER to open/close for an hour while waiting probably for the same reason, as a result of people in the ER.

Guldmann probably never figured out how to fix the issue with the transistor and made a whole new product (Guldmann GH3) rather than fixing the root cause of the GH2.  But the GH3 has it's own issues.  If the red pull safety cord is tugged on or the cord from the wired hand control is tugged on, the hoist shuts off for safety.  Turns out that when spinning in the lift, the hand control will turn the hoist off if turned 360 degrees or close to it, which happens often.  The ergonomics of the GH3 hand control is also terrible when compared to the ergonomics of the GH2 hand control.  The turbo mode also needs to be turned off on the GH3 so a person can use it with dignity.  Turbo mode is on by default!  Hope someone at Guldmann reads this and comments so I can help them fix their GH3 product!  GH2 is still far superior since it doesn't have all these issues and the nylon cable for the hanger bar is not as wide, which makes it easier to spin when required.

Everything below is incorrect from my previous theory.

After switching between multiple GH2 handsets this summer, I'm suspecting the "2510 Pitch 2.54mm 6 Pin Female Connector with 26AWG 30cm Leads" on the refurbished controllers/handsets is the issue.  I've been using refurbished controllers for years.  Recently I bought a new GH2 controller, and I've gone a half month without the traverse issue!  We noticed that one of the 26 guage wires going into the connector was loose on two of the recent refurbished controllers, but not the new one.  The wire is so tiny and slides in and out very easily!  And if you look at my latest question I asked on this site, this new controller also has the "good" rubber sheathing.  More on that later.

[image]

[image]

Here are the parts if I were to buy new connectors:

60 pcs 2510 Pitch 2.54mm 2 Pin Female Connector with 26AWG 30cm Leads Cable New
https://www.ebay.com/itm/233012808389

[image]

60 pcs 2510 Pitch 2.54mm 6 Pin Female Connector with 26AWG 30cm Leads Cable New
https://www.ebay.com/itm/331728351348

[image]